Sharepoint List Validation for Status column
I have a status column in a SharePoint list. I need to write validation to make sure the statuses go in order. The correct order for all entries should be " not started" -> " In Work" -> "Complete". If the Request type column = material site transfer and To location column = Siler city the order should be " not started" -> " In Work" -> " in transit" ->"Complete" but only for entries with that criteria.  Any help would be appreciated, Im not savvy with coding
Ive tried a couple different formulas but to no avail. This was the most recent attempt.
=IF(AND([Request type]="Material Site Transfer", [To location]="Siler City"),
IF(OR(
   AND([Status]="Not started"),
   AND([Status]="In work"),
   AND([Status]="In transit"),
   AND([Status]="Complete")
),
TRUE,
FALSE),
IF(OR(
   AND([Status]="Not started"),
   AND([Status]="In work"),
   AND([Status]="Complete")
),
TRUE,
FALSE)
)


What does "the correct order for all entries" mean? Could you provide some examples?

Sorry for the confusion. By correct order I mean the status order. So when the status of an entry changes it should follow that order. But it is manually updated by an admin of the list, so I would like a way to lock the order in place, so nobody skips a step.
